# How to make maven not show warnings when running jUnit tests which expects exception?

Tags: exception, logging, maven, junit

When maven runs jUnit test which expects exption this exception's stack trace logged and shown in output. Is there is a way how to switch off logging of this. It is quite bothering since build runs well but there is stacktraces in output.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven Surefire Plugin 2.7.2 does not do that. Are you using JUnit 3 or 4?

A test like this does not print any stacktrace, neither in the maven output or in the report file:

```
@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
public void testForExpectedExceptionWithAnnotation()
        throws Exception {
    Integer.parseInt("This should blow up...");
}
```

In jUnit 3, a test like this will also not print a stacktrace. Is your test like this?:

```
public testForExpectedException() throws Exception{
  try{
    Integer.parseInt("This should blow up...");
 }catch(NumberFormatException e){
     //Just ignore it or do some asserts you could need
 }  

 fail("Exceptions not thrown");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the test method not to print the stack trace, since the Surefire runner only displays what is returned by running the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to resolve it I added the following line in the **log4j.properties** used by my unit tests :

```
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
```